VueJs app deployment OK but not components style
I try to deploy my Laravel/VueJs app on OVH with ftp. I already do this without error for other projects. But for the last one I have a problem. The dom is displaying and the css works but not component's styles.
I mean, global css (for h1, h2 ...) works perfectly as the imports of tailwind css (my tailwind's classes are displaying as I want), but all the styles in <style> anchor of my components are not considered and my site looks like my first "hello world" I did.
I do not have errors when I run npm run build neither in development tools like console.
I don't find any solution and I don't understand what's happened, if someone who already have this problem and know how to fix it please help me.
I try many things with my vite.config but it still not displays as I want.
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { createRequire } from 'module';

const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const sass = require('sass');

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      laravel({
          input: ['resources/css/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
          refresh: true,
      }),
      vue(),
    ],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
          vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
          '@': '/resources/js',
      },
    },
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          implementation: sass,
          additionalData: `@import "@/../css/_variables.scss";`,
        },
      },
    },
    build: {
      outDir: 'public/build',
      rollupOptions: {
          output: {
              entryFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].js',
              chunkFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].js',
              assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].[ext]',
          },
      },
    },
});


I just had to call all stylesheets in my app.blade.php. It call all stylesheets referenced in my manifest.json.
Here is my app.blade style anchor :
@if (app()->environment('production'))
            @php
                $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents(public_path('build/manifest.json')), true);
            @endphp
            <script src="{{ asset('build/' . $manifest['resources/js/app.js']['file']) }}" defer></script>
            @foreach ($manifest['resources/js/app.js']['css'] as $cssFile)
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/' . $cssFile) }}">
            @endforeach
        @else
            @vite(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.scss'])
        @endif

